# Select NULL otherwise latest date per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pickup Account with End Date NULL first then latest date if there are more accounts with the same item

Table Sample

[image]

Result expected

[image]

```
Select distinct * 
from Sample
where End Date is null
```

Need help to display the output.

Comment: In your example it is always that all rows for one account have the same date. This is probably not the case in your real database. (If it is then you are violating database normalization and you should make this a separate account table instead, where the date is stored only once per account.) So which account would you choose if account 1 had one record for 2018-01-01 and one record for 2018-03-03? Would you choose account 1 or 2?

Comment: In your example it is always two rows per account, one for Peak and one for Off Peak. Is this always the case? If not, e.g. if there would be no Off Peak record for account 1, would you still want to show it? One row (Peak) only? Or two rows from different accounts, e.g. Peak of account 1 and Off Peak of account 2?

Comment: BTW: With MySQL you should always mention which version you are using. There is a lot that has been added in MySQL 8, so this might affect the answers you are getting.

Comment: Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner, As per account, there will be there type of TOU, Total, Peak, Off Peak and the consumption always having with TOU. The actually table will have more columns of records. Trying to filter out unnecessary accounts and keep the latest and null as max with items.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
from Sample 
order by End_Date is not null, End_date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

According to sample it seems to me you need  union  and not exists corelate subquery

```
select * from table_name t where t.enddate is null
union 
select * from table_name t
where t.endate=( select max(enddate) from table_name t1 where t1.Item=t.Item and t1.Account=t.Account)
and not exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where enddate is null and 
t1 where t2.item=t.item
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY End_Date IS NOT NULL, End_Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

- In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can determine the `end_date_to_consider` for every `Item` (using `GROUP BY Item`). [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) the [`MIN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) date is `NULL`, then we consider `NULL`, else we consider the [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) date.
- Now, we can join this back to the main table on `Item` and the `end_date` to get the required rows.

Try:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM 
  Sample AS t 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    Item, 
    IF(MIN(end_date) IS NULL, 
       NULL, 
       MAX(end_date)) AS end_date_to_consider
  FROM Sample
  GROUP BY Item
) AS dt
  ON dt.Item = t.Item AND
     (dt.end_date_to_consider = t.end_date OR 
      (dt.end_date_to_consider IS NULL AND 
       t.end_date IS NULL)
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should state clearly which result rows you want: **You want one result row per Item and TOU.** For each Item/TOU pair you want the row with highest date, with null having precedence (i.e. being considered the highest possible date).

Is this correct? Does that work with your real accounts? In your example it is always that all rows for one account have a higher date than all other account rows. If that is not the case with your real accounts, you need something more sophisticated than the following solution.

The highest date you can store in MySQL is 9999-12-31. Use this to treat the null dates as desired. Then it's just two steps:

1. Get the highest date per item and tou.
2. Get the row for these item, tou and date.

The query:

```
select * from
sample
where (item, tou, coalesce(enddate, date '9999-12-31') in
(
  select item, tou, max(coalesce(enddate, date '9999-12-31'))
  from sample
  group by item, tou
)
order by item, tou;
```

(If it is possible for your enddate to have the value 9999-12-31 and you want null have precedence over this, then you must consider this in the query, i.e. you can no longer simply use this date in case of null, and the query will get more complicated.)

Comment: Yes. The NULL END date will be used as the highest if there are more accounts with the same item. if the end date is not null and have more accounts with end date, will pick up the highest END date.